# PHP does not issue a warning for undefined variables

Tags: php, warnings, undefined

Please correct me if I am wrong. From what I gather, PHP *should* issue a warning for this but doesn't. I am using PHP 5.2.17. How can I fix this? I am assuming this is set somewhere in php.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the docs for [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). I believe if you enable `E_NOTICE` you'll see warnings for undefined variables. You can read up on all the error reporting constants [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Answer (score 3):

Probably [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is off.

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Or, you are using a variable in a way that it does not have to be declared.